# Elements displayed in list of blog posts in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using the TYPO3 blog extension. I carefully read the documentation provided, created two blog posts and an extra category.

[image]

I managed to display a list of posts but I can't find anywhere **how to choose what is being displayed or not**.

For exemple, **I'd like to remove the comments part, and add, if possible, the first lines of text of each posts**.

I also tried these lines in the blog TS template, that didn't change anything…:

```
plugin.tx_blog.settings.list.posts.dateFormat = %m.%Y
plugin.tx_blog.settings.widgets.comments.active = 0
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how all this works. I've looked in the extension TS templates for some pattern *(the `·` in between all the metadata for exemple)* without any success.

**Where is it all configured ?**

Comment: Please, mark it as resolved if the answer I provided resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to override the view paths to achieve what you want to do. To do so it's easy. First, add those lines in your TypoScript setup :

```
plugin.tx_blog {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPaths.10 = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths.10 = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

Change `your_ext` by the name of your extension that contains your site configuration.

Then copy the templates you want to override (probably `Blog/ListRecentPosts.html` or something like that) in your extension. Be careful to keep the same folder and file names.

Finally change them as you need.

Comment: But where can I see the original files then? I'd like to have a basis on which to work on. I have no idea of what to put in those html files… How can an HTML file configure if a number of comments is displayed or not? How can it configure how to display a few word of an article? I'm sorry but I still don't understand what I have to do…

Comment: Original files are located in `EXT:blog/Resources/Private/{Templates,Layouts,Partials}`. One good thing is to copy these files and adapt them depending on your needs.

Comment: I can't access it from the backend then?

Comment: No you can't. Here are your files : https://bitbucket.typo3.com/projects/EXT/repos/blog/browse/Resources/Private